# Delete a HTMLtable row using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

- Frameworks used: JavaScript, AJAX, HTML. **Cannot use JQuery**
- Have to display SQL table on page
- Last column of the table should contain an image which acts like a delete button
- On clicking that delete image, the row should be deleted from HTML table and SQL table
- In my code the onClick is not working

***HTML code***

table rows displayed by looping through rows of sql query result.

```html
<td>
  <span class="delete" onClick="divFunction()" data-id="<?= $id; ?>"
    ><img src="delete.png"
  /></span>
</td>
```

***JavaScript code***

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  function divFunction() {
    // Storing element that will be deleted
    var el = document.getElementById("delete");
    var deleteid = el.getAttribute("data-id");

    // Creating AJAX request
    var params = "id=" + deleteid;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "remove.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader(
      "Content-type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );
    request.send(params);
    el.remove();
  }
});
```

***PHP Code***

file name: remove.php

```php
if (($con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database", "port"))==false) {
  die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = 0;
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']);
}

// Delete the row
$query = "DELETE FROM Coorporations WHERE id='".$id."'";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
exit;
```

Comment: Just a heads up, your code is *wide* open to a critical SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: "*Cannot use JQuery*" - then why tag the question with [jquery]?

Comment: `onClick="divFunction(this)"` and `function divFunction(el) {` then remove the `var el=`

Comment: @esqew thanks for letting me know about that. I'm planning to shift focus to security once I get the functionality right cause i'm worried of making other errors there.

Comment: Using `document.getElementById('delete')` won't work with your HTML either. The "delete" key is used as a class, not an id. You could try to use something like `document.querySelector('.delete')`, but presumably there will be many rows that have that same class. Using @freedomn-m 's suggestion should help fix that problem.

Comment: You'll have another problem with the `divFunction` method not being visible to the HTML. You're using the `DOMContentLoaded` event to only do things when the DOM is loaded, but you've declared the `divFunction` within the callback of that event registration. Basically, `divFunction` isn't visible outside that callback, and so won't be visible to the `onClick` event in your HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the help. i tried that but the onClick still isn't working. Could it be that there's an error with the JavaScript that's preventing it from working?

Comment: `consolo.log(params);` what value do you get? use `var params = deleteid;` and in your php page `$_POST['deleteid']`.

Comment: @legacybass thank you. How can I make the `divFunction` visible to `onClick`?

Comment: thanks for that spot @Dean I can't get the value of `console.log(params);` as onClick has to work for that first :(  I will try to fix that and then implement it

Comment: Just move it out of the DOMContentLoaded callback. It's just a function, so it doesn't need to wait for anything. Whatever is invoking it might, but the function itself doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and take a guess. You are missing the `delete` id from the element, but you shouldn't be using the id, since that would only return the first element matching. (html standard defines the `id` as being unique)

Instead of `var el = document.getElementById("delete");` you may want to try using the passed target.

Also, as pointed out by @legacybass, you shouldn't define the function in the `DOMContentLoaded` listener-triggered method because it will not get hoisted.

```js
function divFunction(event) {
  // Storing element that will be deleted
  var el = event.target;
  var deleteid = el.getAttribute("data-id");

  // Creating AJAX request
  var params = "id=" + deleteid;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "remove.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  );
  request.send(params);
  el.remove();
}
```

in fact, you may even be able to just pass the id, if it is being rendered by the server.

```html
<td>
  <span class="delete" onClick="divFunction(<?= $id; ?>)" data-id="<?= $id; ?>"
    ><img src="delete.png"
  /></span>
</td>
```

***JavaScript code***

```js
function divFunction(deleteid) {
  // Creating AJAX request
  var params = "id=" + deleteid;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "remove.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  );
  request.send(params);
  el.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might have made things a bit too complicated. Let's assume you've the following table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- 
               Let's not define any onclick handlers here, 
               we'll do that in an instant. 

               For demonstration purposes, let's give all elements 
               a hardcoded id.
            -->
            <span class='delete' data-id='1'>Delete entry</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class='delete' data-id='2'>Delete entry</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inside a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your HTML document, or in a separate file, you might want to try:

```js
// Grab all elements taht should fire an event when clicked  
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.delete');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // Attach an event listener to them    
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // 'e' is the event object itself, 'target' the one
        // that triggered the event in the first place, i.e.
        // one of those <span> elements.
        let element = e.target
        let id      = e.target.dataset.id;

        console.log(id);

        // AJAX stuff
        // ...
    });

}
```

See also:

- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes